# Horrible ethernet speeds on beaglebone

Tags: ubuntu, ethernet, beagleboard, ubuntu-12.10

I'm running a BeagleBone with [eLinux's embedded Ubuntu 12.10](http://elinux.org/BeagleBoardUbuntu). It's hooked up via ethernet, and running horrendously slow - generally in the 3KBps range. My computer, connected to the same network also via ethernet, can get into the 90MBps range (downloading from the same server, of course).

I've check ifconfig and here's the output:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 50:56:63:c6:87:15  
          inet addr:10.0.1.10  Bcast:10.0.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5256:63ff:fec6:8715/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2113 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:856 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:297502 (297.5 KB)  TX bytes:118738 (118.7 KB)
```

Where do I start to debug this? I have no idea what could be causing slow speeds!

Comment: I've tried using `ethtool`, and the only output I get is `Settings for eth0:
 Current message level: 0x00000000 (0)
          
 Link detected: yes
`

Comment: Are you sure it's truly the network? Where are you writing the data that is being downloaded?

Comment: I've tested a bunch of different things – from my laptop to the beaglebone (connected through a hub an a router) starts at 2.1MB/s, but then stalls and I just see the KB/s speed go down and down. I've also tried wgetting files from speedtest.net, and still pulling only 3KB/s maximum.

Comment: If it's not the cable, maybe you should play with the speed/duplex settings (also using ethtool).